# OutOfMemoryError on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, out-of-memory

I'm using a ViewPager with 13 pages. It is managed using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, and each page loads 250ko images as backgrounds, and sometimes 5 images more per page.

I get extremely often an OutOfMemoryError error and I'm testing my app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2, so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Is there a way to release images which are not used on the life cycles of my Fragments on the ViewPager? Any other idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you increase `setOffscreenPageLimit(..)`?

Comment: have a look at this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373059/outofmemeoryerror-viewpager-imageviews http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171857/android-how-to-avoid-the-out-of-memory-exception Best of luck Aamirkhan I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is very well explained and detailed on [Displaying Bitmaps in Your UI](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html)

Answer (score -1):

Setting up the `android:largeHeap` to `true` is also extremely useful for this kind of problems.