# ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter OutOfMemory

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with multiple types of pages (images, videos), so I used FragmentPagerAdapter.

The problem now is, when I have around 14 pages (mostly images) I get an outofmemory error when sliding to the latter ones. I can see a memory leak when changing pages since memory usage only increases and never goes down.

I tried reimplementing the onDEstroyItem method as suggested in other posts, but this seems to work with views instead of Fragments.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) instead of FragmentPagerAdapter as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android).
Also try to decrease the value set by [setOffscreenPageLimit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446687/outofmemoryerror-on-viewpager) as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I keep getting the same error, even when setting setOffScreenPageLimit to 0. It's like there's a memory leak, but I never pass any reference to my Fragments.

Comment: Nope, it was my fault. I was somehow holding up a reference to the fragments. My bad.

Comment: Huh, I thought of asking it when writing an answer, but forgot. =)

Comment: No, your answer was correct. I was using FragmentPagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter, and that was the main cause of the problem. Turns out I additionally made the problem worse by keeping a reference :) Thanks!

Comment: @MichelReap: You cannot set setOffScreenPageLimit to zero. It defaults to one.

Comment: @MichelReap: you generally should not keep references to Fragments as they can be destroyed and recreated by the system at any time, making your references invalid and causing memory leaks

Comment: @MichelReap May I ask that what do you mean by holding up a reference to the fragments? I might have similar problem.