# Live Wallpaper FPS issue

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, frame-rate

I am developing a live wallpaper, in which basically I am rotating around 80 frames (jpg images) - the image size is around 80KB each (800 x 1200 dimension) - total images folder size is around 6 MB.

The images loop fairly smoothly, but as soon as I scale the images (I am doing this to show images well in smaller screens) - the FPS goes for toss - any idea on how to scale the image effectively ?

I thought of two things initially - but it's not working well for me:

1. I thought of putting all the scaled images in ArrayList of Bitmap, but it's giving a `VM Budget error` (tried to do `bitmap.recycle()` too - but it's giving another error like, `trying to use recycle image`). Any thought on this would be highly appreciated.
2. I though of putting scaled images in SD card - but again, don't know why but FPS is getting affected - otherwise this can be the best way where I can detect the size of the phone and can download the images over internet and put it in SD card. But, as I said even this didn't work well.

If anyone can help with either of these approaches, or can point to a better way - that should be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to sample down the image then scale it . this will reduce your memory size. Secondly store this image and use that image there after. you can find sampling and scaling of imager over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641726/decoding-bitmaps-in-android-with-the-right-size/10868883#10868883). Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I have already done scaling and sampling - but those things take time - and FPS is affected when I do any of these operations.

Comment: You must calling every time which might be causing the issue. You should scale it when user changes the orientation.

Comment: my basic image is 1280 x 800 - so if I want to load my lwp in 480 x 800 resolution mobile, I have to scale the image

Comment: You have to first sampling down the image. That will reduce it's memory then scale it as per required.

Comment: sampling doesnt work always - and only power of 2 sampling works good in my case, so sampling wont help over here - and again the issue is, even sampling is time consuming, if I do it everytime.