# How to use Multiple values from Multiple column in sqlite using query?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have five columns and i want to search data from five columns but column values can be more than 5, its not fixed.

Example

column name

first-name,last-name,subject,result,grade.

I want to search more-than one value using sqlite.(first-name can be a,b,c,d)

How to achieve this??

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `IN` keyword in SQLite would allow you perform search with a set of multiple values. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE first-name IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

Now what you can do is to build an input (searchable words) parameter using any loop and replace it in the `IN` brackets.

For example:

```
String names = "'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'";      /* build it through loop */

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE first-name IN (?)",
              new String[]{names});
```

---

**With multiple columns:**

```
String names = "'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'";      /* build it through loop */

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE first-name IN (?)
         OR last-name IN (?) OR subject IN (?) OR result IN (?) OR grade IN (?)",
         new String[]{names, names, names, names, names});
```

Comment: i want to use multiple columns not just one column

Comment: then do the same with multiple columns using `OR` keyword. see my updated answer

Comment: Its working for single value with multiple column,might be i am not using properly for multiple values. String names="'Zac',"Peter""; Is this ok?? how i use multiple string array in selectionArgs??

Comment: can you try my another question? Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156849/live-wallpaper-getting-force-close-issue

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] names = new String[3];
String QueryArgs ="";   
for(int index=0;index < 3;index++)
{
      QueryArgs = QueryArgs.concat(",?");
      names [index] = "xyz";
}
QueryArgs = QueryArgs.substring(1);

Cursor dataset = db.rawquery("select * from table where name in(" +QueryArgs+ ")",names);
```